# How to combine http requests with SSE (Server SentEvents)

Tags: php, codeigniter, server-sent-events

I have a post request that takes a very long time to finish.

I've read all over and got to the conclusion that I need to use SSEs to show the progress.
I can see my progress message in the body of the response, if I stop the http request, but I can't seem to manage a way to fetch only the message (apart from the response body).

It seems I need a PHP script to send to the EventSource class in the FE, but all the scripts have 'No direct script access allowed'.

The info is sent from a library, not from the controller itself, the call is invoked by the controller, using index_post.

Is there another way to get my "echoed" messages from the server to show?

I mostly get

```
 "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection."
```

as an error.
If I put the headers of the eventstream it doesn't help, because it connects to the index page anyway, I still need it as html.

Again, if you have a better suggestion for me, I'd love to hear.

Comment: hope this helps you https://www.howopensource.com/2014/12/introduction-to-server-sent-events/

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I used and got nowhere...
I need something more advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - you don't want to access your scripts directly. Using controllers is absolutely ok.

You can send your output to view or echo your output without using views, like this:

```
echo "data: Hello World!\n\n";
exit;
```

Your main problem is, that you are not sending proper MIME type. Use [output library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html). Look at the example with `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')` and alter it to `$this->output->set_content_type('text/event-stream')`.
You have to put this lines before any output.